# Exporting Node Modules Dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
// module-exports.js
exports.createExports = (exportObject) => {
  module.exports = exportObject
  for (const exportUnit in exportObject) {
    exports[exportUnit] = exportObject[exportUnit]
  }
}
// math.js
const { createExports } = require("./module-export")

const add = (n1, n2) => {
  return n1 + n2
}

const mod = (n1, n2) => {
  return n1 % n2
}

const exportObject = {
  add,
  mod
}

createExports(exportObject)
// app.js
const { add } = require('./math')

console.log('1 + 2 = '.concat(add(1,2))
```

When I try to do something like this, node compiler gives me the error `TypeError: add is not a function` in `app.js`. After a little digging, I found that module is an empty object. What is the proper way of creating exports dynamically in Node.js?

Comment: Why not just do `module.exports = { add, mod }` instead of all this seemingly needless code?

Comment: Or if you really want to create exports from `exportObject` you can just `module.exports = exportObject`

Comment: The problem is that the `module` and `exports` object are different objects in each file. Thus the `module` object inside `module-exports.js` is not the same as the `module` object inside `math.js`. However, the `module` object is just a regular object. If you insist you can do `createExports(module, exportObject)`. And the createExport function is `exports.createExports = (otherModule, exportObject) => ...` but I don't see any reason to do this because it does the same thing as `module.exports = exportObject`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman), I see the solution now. My main motive was to get rid of the struggle of writing multiple `exports.[name]` for each module. Though using Object deconstruction, the question is unnecessary. Since:

```js
exports.m = () => '@m'
module.exports = {
  m: () => '@m'
}
// Both of these m functions can be accessed with the same method
const { m } = require('./module')
```

As stated, each module has a unique module object for exports. Injecting this module object and using it as a parameter is the solution for this question.